# Not able to see Worklight settings option in android phones?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I recently started to work with Worklight 6.1 developer edition, to create an android application. My previous version of the application, deployed on my nexus 5 I was able to view the Worklight settings option, to change my server URL and so on.
see it Here::
http://www.connoisseur.comli.com/screenshots/Screenshot_nexus.png

Later on I was not able to view this Settings option.
Here::
http://www.connoisseur.comli.com/screenshots/Screenshot_2014-03-21-19-03-47.png

My Application Desciptor file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
         5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
         US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
         disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. --><!--   Attribute "id" must be identical to application folder name --><application xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/application-descriptor" id="MF_PIZZA" platformVersion="6.1.0.00.20131219-1900">
<displayName>MF_PIZZA</displayName>
<description>MF_PIZZA</description>
<author>
    <name>application's author</name>
    <email>application author's e-mail</email>
    <homepage>http://mycompany.com</homepage>
    <copyright>Copyright My Company</copyright>
</author>
<mainFile>MF_PIZZA.html</mainFile>
<features>
    <JSONStore/>
    <Analytics/>
</features>
<thumbnailImage>common/images/thumbnail.png</thumbnailImage>
<iphone bundleId="com.MFPIZZA" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    </security>
</iphone>
<android version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the actual public signing key of the certificate used to sign the APK, available by using the 'Extract public signing key' wizard.</publicSigningKey>
    </security>
</android>
</application>
```

I have added the third scenario in the comments because I was not able to post more than two links because of my constraints in Reputation.

Comment: When I tried to do the same in my micromax A116, this was the outcome:: http://www.connoisseur.comli.com/screenshots/Screenshot_2014-03-21-19-07-07.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to this question: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Questions about "Worklight Settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860648/ibm-worklight-6-1-questions-about-worklight-settings)

It is a detailed answer explaining why you may or may not see the Menu button in Android.
Basically, it depends on the used API Level for the Android project in combination with the used OS version used. Starting from a certain API level, the Options Menu in Android was removed (by Android) and replaced by the Action bar. Worklight does not support the Action bar, which is why you will not see the Menu option.

This is a known missing feature in the product.

---

From the comments:

> During development, Is it possible to change the server URL statically
>   without the settings feature?

1. You can set a remote server address [using the Build Settings and Deploy Target dialog](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html).
2. You can also copy `android\native\wlclinet.properties` to the `nativeResources` folder and edit the properties in it. Upon build, this file will be copied to the `native` folder

In both options the change is done prior to building the app, and not during runtime.

Comment: So is there any other way to change the server URL manually from the application?

Comment: You do realize this feature is meant for testing only and not for production?

Comment: Other than the Worklight Settings option, which again is for testing only, Worklight does not officialy support change the server URL an application connects to. There is a hack, but implementing it means voiding support if things go wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258784/re-route-divert-some-wl-client-adapter-invocation-traffic-to-wl-server-through-d

Comment: During development, Is it possible to change the server URL statically without the settings feature?

Comment: @user3446786, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.